# Break loop inside a delegate

Tags: c#, loops, delegates

I created simple class, which can use to create loops:

```
public class SimpleLoop
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public Predicate<int> Condition { get; set; }
    public int Increment { get; set; }
    public Action<int> Action { get; set; }

    public SimpleLoop(int i, Predicate<int> condition, int increment, Action<int> action)
    {
        I = i;
        Condition = condition;
        Increment = increment;
        Action = action;
        Invoke();
    }

    private void Invoke()
    {
        for (int i = I; Condition.Invoke(i); i += Increment)
        {
            Action.Invoke(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can call this loop this way:

```
new SimpleLoop(0, i => i <= 12, 1, delegate (int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```

Everything works fine, but I don't know how to break out of the loop, because I can't use the keywords `break` and `continue` inside a `void`. I found out that I can use `return` to get same effect as `continue`, but I can't break out of the loop.

I also created other "loop classes" on the base of this class. They look quite similar, but there I use a customized delegate instead of `Action`

Comment: I assume that this is just to play with code... because it's almost useless in production code :\

Comment: You can just make the invoked function return a boolean stating whether to continue or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a `Func<int, bool>` instead of `Action<int>`, and require that the delegate return `true` to continue or `false` to break?

For example:

```
public class SimpleLoop
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public Predicate<int> Condition { get; set; }
    public int Increment { get; set; }
    public Func<int, bool> Action { get; set; }

    public SimpleLoop(int i, Predicate<int> condition, int increment, Func<int, bool> action)
    {
        I = i;
        Condition = condition;
        Increment = increment;
        Action = action;
        Invoke();
    }

    private void Invoke()
    {
        for (int i = I; Condition.Invoke(i); i += Increment)
        {
            if (!Action.Invoke(i))
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
new SimpleLoop(0, i => i <= 12, 1, delegate (int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    return i < 5;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is the best solution, but I would use an `enum` instead of a `bool`, so that I can choose between `break`, `continue` and nothing

Answer (score 0):

Use the same way as Paralell Linq does it.
Your delegate should not just take the value, but also an object that represents the state of the iteration itself.

```
Action<int> action
```

becomes

```
Action<SimpleLoopState, int> ...


delegate (state, value) => 
{
state.Break();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you were trying to break the loop;
I tried breaking it at value 9, and it worked.
Here is the code

```
enter code here
   private void Invoke()
    {
        for (int i = I; Condition.Invoke(i); i += Increment)
        {
            Action.Invoke(i);
            if(i.Equals(9))
            break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Manish Prasad

Comment: i.Equals(9) is the same thing as i==9

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to break out of the loop. I created a class based on the class `Exception` and called it `BreakException`:

```
public class BreakException : Exception { }
```

Then I added a static method to throw one `BreakException`:

```
public static void Break()
{ throw new BreakException(); }
```

Now I can catch this Exception to break out of the loop:

```
private void Invoke()
{
    for (int i = I; Condition.Invoke(i); i += Increment)
    {
        try
        {
            Action.Invoke(i);
        }
        catch (BreakException)
        { break; }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** If I call the `Break`-method inside a `try-catch` block I have to make sure, that I don't catch a `BreakException` and if I catch one I have to call the `Break`-method again:

```
new SimpleLoop(0, i => i <= 12, 1, delegate (int i)
{
    try
    {
        if (i == 5)
        { throw new ArgumentException(); }//raise an other Exception 
        if (i > 10)
        { SimpleLoop.Break(); }
          Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)//Catching every Exception, it would be better to catch just ArgumentExceptions
    {
        if (exception.GetType() == typeof(BreakException))
        { SimpleLoop.Break(); }//Call Break again
        Console.WriteLine("Error at " + i);
    }
});
```

Comment: An exception will cost you a lot of performance (relative to the work you are doing). In many projects a performance cost that big for something that is likely widely used is not acceptable...